# How do I parse Google image URLs using Ruby and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm trying to make an array of all the image files on a Google images webpage.

I want a regular expression to pull everything after `"imagurl="` and ending before `"&amp"` as seen in this HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-   christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/silent-night-chapel-20031-christmas-ornament-old-world-christmas.html&amp;usg=__YJdf3xc4ydSfLQa9tYnAzavKHYQ=&amp;h=400&amp;w=400&amp;sz=58&amp;hl=en&amp;start=19&amp;zoom=1&amp;tbnid=ajDcsGGs0tgE9M:&amp;tbnh=124&amp;tbnw=124&amp;ei=qagfUbXmHKfv0QHI3oG4CQ&amp;itbs=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0CE4QrQMwEg"><img height="124" width="124" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLy5inpSdHxWuE7z3QSZw35JwN3upbBaLr11LR25noTKbSMn9-qrySSg"></a><br><cite title="trendytree.com">trendytree.com</cite><br>Silent Night Chapel <b>20031</b><br>400 × 400 - 58k - jpg</td>
```

I feel like I can do this with a regex, but I can't find a way to search my parsed document using regex, but I'm not finding any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = '<a href="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-     christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/silent-night-chapel-20031-christmas-ornament-old-world-christmas.html&amp;usg=__YJdf3xc4ydSfLQa9tYnAzavKHYQ=&amp;h=400&amp;w=400&amp;sz=58&amp;hl=en&amp;start=19&amp;zoom=1&amp;tbnid=ajDcsGGs0tgE9M:&amp;tbnh=124&amp;tbnw=124&amp;ei=qagfUbXmHKfv0QHI3oG4CQ&amp;itbs=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0CE4QrQMwEg"><img height="124" width="124" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLy5inpSdHxWuE7z3QSZw35JwN3upbBaLr11LR25noTKbSMn9-qrySSg"></a><br><cite title="trendytree.com">trendytree.com</cite><br>Silent Night Chapel <b>20031</b><br>400 × 400 - 58k - jpg</td>'
str.split('imgurl=')[1].split('&amp')[0]
#=> "http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-     christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg"
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using a regex is you assume too much knowledge about the order of parameters in the URL. If the order changes, or `&amp;` disappears the regex won't work.

Instead, parse the URL, then split the values out:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'nokogiri'
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<a href="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/silent-night-chapel-20031-christmas-ornament-old-world-christmas.html&amp;usg=__YJdf3xc4ydSfLQa9tYnAzavKHYQ=&amp;h=400&amp;w=400&amp;sz=58&amp;hl=en&amp;start=19&amp;zoom=1&amp;tbnid=ajDcsGGs0tgE9M:&amp;tbnh=124&amp;tbnw=124&amp;ei=qagfUbXmHKfv0QHI3oG4CQ&amp;itbs=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0CE4QrQMwEg"><img height="124" width="124" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLy5inpSdHxWuE7z3QSZw35JwN3upbBaLr11LR25noTKbSMn9-qrySSg"></a><br><cite title="trendytree.com">trendytree.com</cite><br>Silent Night Chapel <b>20031</b><br>400 × 400 - 58k - jpg</td>')

img_url = doc.search('a').each do |a|
  query_params = CGI::parse(URI(a['href']).query) 
  puts query_params['imgurl']
end
```

Which outputs:

```
http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg
```

Both URI and CGI are used because URI's `decode_www_form` raises an exception when trying to decode the query.

I've also been known to decode the query string into a hash using something like:

```
Hash[URI(a['href']).query.split('&').map{ |p| p.split('=') }]
```

That will return:

```
{"imgurl"=>
  "http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/images/20031chapel20031-silent-night-chapel.jpg",
 "imgrefurl"=>
  "http://www.trendytree.com/old-world-christmas/silent-night-chapel-20031-christmas-ornament-old-world-christmas.html",
 "usg"=>"__YJdf3xc4ydSfLQa9tYnAzavKHYQ",
 "h"=>"400",
 "w"=>"400",
 "sz"=>"58",
 "hl"=>"en",
 "start"=>"19",
 "zoom"=>"1",
 "tbnid"=>"ajDcsGGs0tgE9M:",
 "tbnh"=>"124",
 "tbnw"=>"124",
 "ei"=>"qagfUbXmHKfv0QHI3oG4CQ",
 "itbs"=>"1",
 "sa"=>"X",
 "ved"=>"0CE4QrQMwEg"}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the img urls you want do

```
# get all links
url = 'some-google-images-url'
links = Nokogiri::HTML( open(url) ).css('a')

# get regex match or nil on desired img
img_urls = links.map {|a| a['href'][/imgurl=(.*?)&/, 1] }

# get rid of nils
img_urls.compact
```

The regex you want is `/imgurl=(.*?)&/` because you want a non-greedy match between `imgurl=` and `&`, otherwise the greedy `.*` would take everything to the last `&` in the string.